# how to insert picture or image into oracle database?

Tags: oracle

```
<code>
 sql>CREATE TABLE Employees
     (
     Id int,
     Name varchar(50) not null,
     Photo varbinary(max) not null
     ) 
</code>
```

This code is showing error like this:
                                    photo varbinary(max) not null
                                                   *
                                     ERROR at line 5:
                                    ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
Please help

Comment: `varbinary` is not a data type in Oracle.  Are you using SQL Server?  Or is your actual DDL using a BLOB data typr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`BLOB (Binary Large Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/types.htm#TTSQL482) which is ideal for storing multimedia content like images.

Check this out for [storing images using BLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28845/ch7.htm#i1037547).

Comment: SQL> desc graphics............................................................
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------
 BFILE_ID                                           NUMBER.........
 BFILE_DESC                                         VARCHAR2(30)....
 BFILE_LOC                                          BINARY FILE LOB.
 BFILE_TYPE                                         VARCHAR2(4)     This is type of BLOB table but I don't know how to insert picture into this table,I mean in which format????

Comment: are you using oracle sql developer?

Comment: can you post some code snippet as well which you are using to insert into oracle.

Comment: sir I don't know how to insert image into the database................. I am beginner for all this................... I have created a new file as Dileep sir given above but again sql is not accepting the image given by that code...........

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table like below and insert into the table, below are the sample scripts for that

```
create table graphics_table (
  bfile_id number,
  bfile_desc varchar2(30),
  bfile_loc bfile,
  bfile_type varchar2(4));

INSERT INTO graphics_table
   VALUES(4,'April Book of Days Woodcut',bfilename('GIF_FILES','APRIL.JPG'),'JPEG');
INSERT INTO graphics_table
  VALUES(30,'',bfilename('GIF_FILES','SHAPIROS.GIF'),'GIF');

If u need more Info on this please refer to 

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_storing_insert_photo_pictures_tables.htm
```

Comment: By inserting images using this script table gets created but again problem occurs at insert into command..................................

Comment: wt's d error u r getting.. or else read this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_storing_insert_photo_pictures_tables.htm

Answer (score -1):

First the question that has been posted is for SQL

varbinary(max) is a  new  datatype in sql2012

Cast f(x) will be  used in order to convert the image  into Binary format.

The  insert query for the  insertion of image is

insert into Employees values(1, 'ABC', cast('path\abc.jpeg') as varbinary(max));