# Adding images to Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and I'm trying to add images from a folder on my desktop to the database. I have a table consisting of:

```
id          number
Name        varchar 
description clob
thumbnail   blob
image       ordimage
filename    varchar2
```

I want to be able to add an image to this table.

Is there a way I can manually add them or is their any code tips or help I can get?

Comment: Hi @donald-bury, welcome to SO. First thing : Please read this for your future questions -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

For your current question - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435594/how-to-insert-picture-or-image-into-oracle-database

Comment: I didn't see an ordimage datatype here.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm

Comment: Oracle Multimedia ORDImage Object Type @DanBracuk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sql-Developer, you neet to click on the table on the right side, 
then select "Data" tab, then insert new row (or select existing row), 
next click to BLOB column, on the following dialog click to "Load" option,
then select an image and upload it to the table from local disc
See attached picture.
[image]

Comment: How could i get it to keep the filename in the table and ordimage file?

Comment: Create a column of Varchar2 type, name this column "filename", and store filenames in this column.